# spring mvc + desktop app = best protocol and gui framework

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, swing, soap, desktop

I wanna create spring app which will consists of 2 parts :

- spring backend + spring mvc (server + web app)
- desktop app which need to acces to backend

Whats best protocol to comunicate between spring and desktop app? Can i use SOAP for this? Can someone do quick overview of avaliable technologies (why not/yes)?

And whats best choice for desktop app GUI framework? or its better to use pure Swing / AWT.

I want to notice that i wanna use solutions which is most popular in software companies.

I appreciate every opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The companies I work for aren't interested in Swing.  Apps are web-based, not desktop.  You're more likely to find mobile apps rather than Swing these days.

With that said, your instinct is a good one: separate the services, which are unlikely to change, from the UIs that come and go.

Start with Spring POJO, interface-based services and remote them any way you like.

An HTTP-based protocol will be more reusable by different clients.

Spring allows you to use HTTP remoting, SOAP or REST web services.  If you write web services, learn how to write "contract first".  Start with the .xsd for your XML messages.

Comment: great thanks. i have one more question about webservices. i wanted to comunicate with them by swing app but if you say desktop is not needed, so what for i need webservices? mobile apps and other sites? I will use spring mvc in same container so all services are at same place.

Comment: Web services expose your business logic to any client that can connect via HTTP.  Those include web, mobile, and even Swing desktops if you disagree with me and decide to go that way.  Spring MVC is part of the client and has nothing to do with web services.